# "Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined" (same for Router, Meteor, Mongo)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

Trying to port [Crowducate](http://crowducate.me) from Meteor 0.8 to 1.0. I ran "meteor update".
Branch for Meteor 1.0 is --> [here](https://github.com/Crowducate/crowducate.me/tree/port-to-Meteor-1.0).

I had update-issues, i.e. I couldn't remove the "old" iron-router for the "new" iron:router. So currently, both versions are installed (this has to change, of course). Meteor package file:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

# Packages by Meteor
standard-app-packages
preserve-inputs
audit-argument-checks
spiderable
less
coffeescript
accounts-password
accounts-facebook
accounts-google
accounts-ui

# Packages by community
minimongoid
iron-router
iron:router
kaptron:minimongoid

# Packages by Manuel Schoebel
```

Running meteor: Gives the following error:

[image]

In the end, I also get the following error:

```
Exception in defer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
at Utils.extend.autoRender (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?af9f4791b8af4582a37d93bcade1eed163a976a8:1636:17)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?af9f4791b8af4582a37d93bcade1eed163a976a8:1465:16
at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?61916b1060b33931a21f104fbffb67c2f3d493c5:945:17)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?61916b1060b33931a21f104fbffb67c2f3d493c5:430:45
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?61916b1060b33931a21f104fbffb67c2f3d493c5:973:22)
at onGlobalMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?61916b1060b33931a21f104fbffb67c2f3d493c5:367:23)
```

So most things are undefined. I also locally changed Meteor.Collection to Mongo.Collection. Now, both are undefined.

Thanks for trying to help out,
Amir

*Side note*: Always looking for collaborators on this project. Contact me. :)

Comment: Try putting your collections under `lib` so they get loaded first.

Comment: @DavidWeldon: thx for the tip :) done, but won't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

I also had these errors given I had installed Iron Router via meteorite:

```
$ mrt add iron-router
```

This installed an older version which is incompatible with Meteor 1.x.
Try removing iron-router via meteorite and installing via meteor:

```
$ mrt remove iron-router
$ meteor add iron:router
```

Just to be safe run reset before relaunching:

```
$ meteor reset
$ meteor
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.  I tried following @Jason's instructions but kept getting:

```
error: unknown package in top-level dependencies: iron-router
```

when I tried to install iron:router.  Thanks to [this](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/qa-x1hVdypg) thread I finally got the issue resolved by removing `iron-router` from `.meteor/packages`.  Apparently `mrt remove iron-router` doesn't completely remove all traces of `iron-router`.

Answer (score 1):

For `template undefined` error,

try run `meteor reset` command and then start server with `meteor`

**Note**: `meteor reset` will do reset your build and also local mongodb data

**Update**: It should remove the error but anyways try full uninstall of `meteor` from your system and install it again.

The meteor core installation might get corrupted while auto updating from 0.8 to 1.0 version

**Uninstall meteor -**

`rm -rf ~/.meteor`

`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/meteor`

**Install**

`curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

Above will install latest version of meteor i.e 1.0

and after that now update your project with

`cd <your-project-directory>`

`meteor update --release 1.0.0`

Comment: @AmirRahbaran Updated answer, check it out

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
meteor remove iron-router